# Implementing Clojure conditional/branching transducer

Tags: clojure, conditional-statements, transducer

I'm trying to make a conditional transducer in Clojure as follows:

```
(defn if-xf
  "Takes a predicate and two transducers.
   Returns a new transducer that routes the input to one of the transducers
   depending on the result of the predicate."
  [pred a b]
  (fn [rf]
    (let [arf (a rf)
          brf (b rf)]
      (fn
        ([] (rf))
        ([result]
           (rf result))
        ([result input]
           (if (pred input)
             (arf result input)
             (brf result input)))))))
```

It is pretty useful in that it lets you do stuff like this:

```
;; multiply odd numbers by 100, square the evens.  
(= [0 100 4 300 16 500 36 700 64 900]
    (sequence
          (if-xf odd? (map #(* % 100)) (map (fn [x] (* x x))))
          (range 10)))
```

However, this conditional transducer does not work very well with transducers that perform cleanup in their 1-arity branch:

```
;; negs are multiplied by 100, non-negs are partitioned by 2
;; BUT! where did 6 go?
;; expected: [-600 -500 -400 -300 -200 -100 [0 1] [2 3] [4 5] [6]]
;;
(= [-600 -500 -400 -300 -200 -100 [0 1] [2 3] [4 5]]
 (sequence
  (if-xf neg? (map #(* % 100)) (partition-all 2))
  (range -6 7)))
```

Is it possible to tweak the definition of `if-xf` to handle the case of transducers with cleanup?

I'm trying this, but with weird behavior:

```
(defn if-xf
  "Takes a predicate and two transducers.
   Returns a new transducer that routes the input to one of the transducers
   depending on the result of the predicate."
  [pred a b]
  (fn [rf]
    (let [arf (a rf)
          brf (b rf)]
      (fn
        ([] (rf))
        ([result]
           (arf result) ;; new!
           (brf result) ;; new!
           (rf result))
        ([result input]
           (if (pred input)
             (arf result input)
             (brf result input)))))))
```

Specifically, the flushing happens at the end:

```
;; the [0] at the end should appear just before the 100.
(= [[-6 -5] [-4 -3] [-2 -1] 100 200 300 400 500 600 [0]]
      (sequence
       (if-xf pos? (map #(* % 100)) (partition-all 2))
       (range -6 7)))
```

Is there a way to make this branching/conditional transducer without storing the entire input sequence in local state within this transducer (i.e. doing all the processing in the 1-arity branch upon cleanup)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to complete every time the transducer switches over. IMO this is the only way to do it without buffering:

```
(defn if-xf
  "Takes a predicate and two transducers.
   Returns a new transducer that routes the input to one of the transducers
   depending on the result of the predicate."
  [pred a b]
  (fn [rf]
    (let [arf (volatile! (a rf))
          brf (volatile! (b rf))
          a? (volatile! nil)]
      (fn
        ([] (rf))
        ([result]
         (let [crf (if @a? @arf @brf)]
           (-> result crf rf)))
        ([result input]
         (let [p? (pred input)
               [xrf crf] (if p? [@arf @brf] [@brf @arf])
               switched? (some-> @a? (not= p?))]
           (if switched?
             (-> result crf (xrf input))
             (xrf result input))
           (vreset! a? p?)))))))
(sequence (if-xf pos? (map #(* % 100)) (partition-all 2)) [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1])
; => ([0] 100 [0] 100 [0 0] [0] 100)
```

Comment: `(sequence (if-xf pos? (map #(* % 100)) (partition-all 2)) [-1 1 0])` gives `([-1] 100)` in your example, this may not be what OP want

Comment: You're right. I need to remove the `vresets` and it's working. But now I don't understand anymore why it's not working. :(

Comment: Why do `arf` and `brf` need to be volatile -- they don't appear to change? I think with the restriction that we can't buffer, this is probably the best possible. Unfortunately this solution doesn't quite work in pathological cases, (e.g. if one of the argument transducers buffers everything and does all the work in the 1-arg completion step). It would be super cool if there was a graceful degradation, where if neither input xducer buffers, then the `if` wouldn't buffer, and otherwise it buffers to the extent needed. Transducers aren't magical yet, though.

Comment: My initial implementation was to restart the transducers every time it switches over from `a` to `b` (hence the volatile) but it didn't work and I didnt have the time to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is ill-defined. What exactly do you want to happen when the transducers have state? For example, what do you expect this do:

```
(sequence
  (if-xf even? (partition-all 3) (partition-all 2))
  (range 14))
```

Furthermore, sometimes reducing functions have work to do at the beginning and the end and can't be restarted arbitrarily. For example, here is a reducer that computes the mean:

```
(defn mean
  ([] {:count 0, :sum 0})
  ([result] (double (/ (:sum result) (:count result))))
  ([result x]
   (update-in
     (update-in result [:count] inc)
     [:sum] (partial + x))))
(transduce identity mean [10 20 40 40]) ;27.5
```

Now let's take the average, where anything below 20 counts for 20, but everything else is decreased by 1:

```
(transduce
  (if-xf
    (fn [x] (< x 20))
    (map (constantly 20))
    (map dec))
  mean [10 20 40 40]) ;29.25
```

My answer is the following: I think your original solution is best. It works well using `map`, which is how you stated the usefulness of the conditional transducer in the first place.